# Scene for Computer Screen

Tags: unity, 2d, 3d, unityscript, user-interface

We are developing a scene that will involve heavily interacting with a "touch screen monitor" in the scene.. Because the workflow of the touch screen will need to be dynamic we are creating a REST API that Unity will fetch JSON data and use that to build out the various parts of the UI. For instance, we get a JSON file that has a list of users and attributes and build out UI elements with that data.

The question is should I build out the display and underlying logic as a 2D scene that I add in to our 3D room or just build it all in the 3D scene.

I want to abstract away as much of the logic as I can for the interactive screen; I want to make sure we can drop this screen in a different Scene down the road without too much reverse-engineering.

Sorry if this is a straightforward question, my background is software dev, not game design.

Comment: ...what? Are you saying that inside your 3D scene you will have a "touch screen monitor" object that the user interacts with?

Comment: Correct, inside our 3D scene will be a touch screen (Think a Kiosk or ATM). Sorry for the ambiguity